# Can we pray isha early in Summer?

Tags: salat

Is it allowed to read prayer isha little before its time in summer? Because isha happen at 10:45 and we have to wake up for work 4:30 in the morning. And not getting enough sleep makes me very cranky and I even can't get a nap during the day time.

Answer (score 2):

In the name of Allah, Most Gracious, Most Merciful

Assalaamu `alaykum waRahmatullahi Wabarakatuh

The time if ‘Isha commences upon the disappearance of the whiteness of the sky (Al-Shafq al-Abyad) according to Imam Abu Hanifa (ra) and upon the disappearance of the redness of the sky (Al-Shafq al-Ahmar) according to Imam Abu Yusuf (ra) and Imam Muhammad (ra).

In high latitude countries, the whiteness in the sky remains in the sky during the summer days and at times the redness also does not disappear.  According to some Jurists, the ‘Isha prayer is not obligatory since the time of ‘Isha never sets in. However other ‘Ulama have stated that salat will still be obligatory and this is a more precautionary view.

If it is a locality where the redness disappears but the whiteness remains, then the ‘Isha time will commence upon the redness disappearing. This is the view of Imam Abu Yusuf (ra) and Imam Muhammad (ra) and is a valid, accepted view within the madhhab.

If it is a locality where the redness in the sky also does not disappear or the sun never sets below the horizon, then Jurists have given different options to what should be done for the daily salats.

·        The timings of salat should be calculated based upon that day of the year which has a normal, balanced timing.

·        The timings salat should be calculated based upon the last day in which there was a normal night, i.e. the redness and the whiteness disappeared.

·        The timings for the salat should be calculated based upon the nearest locality that has a normal day and night.

One should adopt an option in which the remainder of the locality is practicing upon so the community can perform the salats with congregation. If one is uncertain about which method of calculation is right for him, then he should consult the local scholars and practice upon their advice.

It would not be correct to stipulate a general time such as 1 ½ hours after Maghrib for the time of ‘Isha. The timing of salat is not calculated by fixed times but it depends on the movement of the sun. We understand that it is difficult to practice upon the stipulated time of salat, especially when the days are long and Fajr is very early. If one is in extreme difficulty, then he may perform the ‘Isha salat right before the Fajr time is about to commence and then perform Fajr salat thereafter. (This is known as Jama’ Suwari)

Rad al-Muhtar (1/362) H.M. Saeed

Ahsan al-Fatawa (2/113) H.M. Saeed

فى در المختار: ( وفاقد وقتهما ) كبلغار ، فإن فيها يطلع الفجر قبل غروب الشفق في أربعينية الشتاء ( مكلف بهما فيقدر لهما ) ولا ينوي القضاء لفقد وقت الأداء به أفتى البرهان الكبير واختاره الكمال ، وتبعه ابن الشحنة في ألغازه فصححه ، فزعم المصنف أنه المذهب ( وقيل لا ) يكلف بهما لعدم سببهما ، وبه جزم في الكنز والدرر والملتقى وبه أفتى البقالي ، ووافقه الحلواني والمرغيناني ورجحه الشرنبلالي والحلبي ، وأوسعا المقال ومنعا ما ذكره الكمال قلت : ولا يساعده حديث الدجال ؛ لأنه وإن وجب أكثر من ثلثمائة ظهر مثلا قبل الزوال ليس كمسألتنا ؛ لأن المفقود فيه العلامة لا الزمان ، وأما فيها فقد فقد الأمران .

فى رد المحتار: بقي الكلام في معنى التقدير ، والذي يظهر من عبارة الفيض أن المراد أنه يجب قضاء العشاء ، بأن يقدر أن الوقت أعني سبب الوجوب قد وجد كما يقدر وجوده في أيام الدجال على ما يأتي ؛ لأنه لا يجب بدون السبب ، فيكون قوله ويقدر الوقت جوابا عن قوله في الأول لعدم السبب . وحاصله أنا لا نسلم لزوم وجود السبب حقيقة بل يكفي تقديره كما في أيام الدجال . ويحتمل أن المراد بالتقدير المذكور هو ما قاله الشافعية من أنه يكون وقت العشاء في حقهم بقدر ما يغيب فيه الشفق في أقرب البلاد إليهم ، والمعنى الأول أظهر ،...والأحسن في الجواب عن المحقق الكمال ابن الهمام أنه لم يذكر حديث الدجال ليقيس عليه مسألتنا أو يلحقها به دلالة ، وإنما ذكره دليلا على افتراض الصلوات الخمس وإن لم يوجد السبب افتراضا عاما ؛ لأن قوله وما روي معطوف على قوله ما تواطأت عليه أخبار الإسراء ، وما أورده عليه من عدم الافتراض على الحائض والكافر يجاب عنه بما قاله المحشي من ورود النص بإخراجهما من العموم . هذا وقد أقر ما ذكره المحقق تلميذاه العلامتان المحققان ابن أمير حاج والشيخ قاسم . والحاصل أنهما قولان مصححان ، ويتأيد القول بالوجوب بأنه قال به إمام مجتهد وهو الإمام الشافعي كما نقله في الحلية عن المتولي عنه . ( قوله : ولا يساعده ) الضمير راجع إلى ما ذكره الكمال ح . ( قوله : حديث الدجال ) هو ما قدمناه في كلام الكمال . قال الإسنوي : فيستثنى هذا اليوم مما ذكر في المواقيت ، ويقاس اليومان التاليان له . قال الرملي في شرح المنهاج : ويجري ذلك فيما لو مكثت الشمس عند قوم مدة . ا هـ . ح . قال في إمداد الفتاح قلت : وكذلك يقدر لجميع الآجال كالصوم والزكاة والحج والعدة وآجال البيع والسلم والإجارة ، وينظر ابتداء اليوم فيقدر كل فصل من الفصول الأربعة بحسب ما يكون كل يوم من الزيادة والنقص كذا في كتب الأئمة الشافعية ، ونحن نقول بمثله إذ أصل التقدير مقول به إجماعا في الصلوات ا هـ .

2.

If blood becomes apparent inside an egg, the spots of blood will be impure and unlawful to consume. If the spots of blood are removed without it contaminating the other parts of the egg, then the egg will no longer remain impure and will be lawful to consume. The removal of blood is related to all types of blood marks and not only those that seem fresh.

بيضة مذرت ، فهى نجسة ، لأنها تتحول دما بخلاف اللبن ، لأنه يتغير بالفساد طعمه ، وبتغير الطعم لا يتنجس ، كذا فى ((القنية)) عن (خو) أي الخمير الوبري رحمه الله . – فتاوى اللكنوى ص 115 دار ابن حزم

في «القدوري»: إذا ماتت فأرة في مائع كالسمن ونحوه، فإن كان ذائبا تنجس وجاز الانتفاع به في غير الأبدان وجاز بيعه، على البائع أن يبين ذلك للمشتري. وإن كان جامدا تلقى ويقور ما حولها ويلقى وينتفع بالباقي أكلا وغير ذلك، والأصل فيه ما روي أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم سئل عن سمن وقعت فيه فأرة وماتت قال: «إن كان جامدا فألقوها وما حولها وكلوا الباقي وإن كان ذائبا فانتفعوا به ولا تأكلوه»؛ ولأن في الجامد النجاسة جاورت موضعا واحدا، فإذا قور ذلك فالباقي طاهر، وفي الذائب النجاسة جاورت الكل فصار الكل نجسا. وحد الجمود والذوبان: أنه إذا كان بحال لو قور ذلك الموضع لا يستوي من ساعته فهو جامد، وإن كان يستوي من ساعته فهو ذائب – المحيط البرهاني ( ج1 ص123)  دار إحياء التراث العربي

And Allah knows best

Answer (score 1):

[This website](http://salah.com/) gives you the recommended timing for prayer for different location and different dates.

Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) did not mind varying time for the Isha prayer.

> [Narrated Abu Al-Minhal](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/9):
>   Abu Barza said, "The Prophet (PUBH) used to offer the Fajr (prayer) when one could recognize the person sitting by him (after the prayer) and he used to recite between 60 to 100 Ayat (verses) of the Qur'an. He used to offer the Zuhr prayer as soon as the sun declined (at noon) and the Asr at a time when a man might go and return from the farthest place in Medina and find the sun still hot. (The sub-narrator forgot what was said about the Maghrib). He did not mind delaying the `Isha prayer to one third of the night or the middle of the night."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا حَفْصُ بْنُ عُمَرَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ أَبِي الْمِنْهَالِ، عَنْ أَبِي بَرْزَةَ، كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم يُصَلِّي الصُّبْحَ وَأَحَدُنَا يَعْرِفُ جَلِيسَهُ، وَيَقْرَأُ فِيهَا مَا بَيْنَ السِّتِّينَ إِلَى الْمِائَةِ، وَيُصَلِّي الظُّهْرَ إِذَا زَالَتِ الشَّمْسُ، وَالْعَصْرَ وَأَحَدُنَا يَذْهَبُ إِلَى أَقْصَى الْمَدِينَةِ ثُمَّ يَرْجِعُ وَالشَّمْسُ حَيَّةٌ، وَنَسِيتُ مَا قَالَ فِي الْمَغْرِبِ، وَلاَ يُبَالِي بِتَأْخِيرِ الْعِشَاءِ إِلَى ثُلُثِ اللَّيْلِ‏.‏ ثُمَّ قَالَ إِلَى شَطْرِ اللَّيْلِ‏.‏ وَقَالَ مُعَاذٌ قَالَ شُعْبَةُ ثُمَّ لَقِيتُهُ مَرَّةً فَقَالَ أَوْ ثُلُثِ اللَّيْلِ‏.‏

Especially in this [sunnah](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/9/37):

> Narrated Jabir bin Abdullah:
>   The Prophet (PBUH) used to pray the Zuhr at midday, and the Asr at a time when the sun was still bright, the Maghrib after sunset (at its stated time) and the Isha at a variable time. Whenever he saw the people assembled (for`Isha' prayer) he would pray earlier and if the people delayed, he would delay the prayer. And they or the Prophet (PBUH) used to offer the Fajr Prayers when it still dark.
>
> حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بَشَّارٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ جَعْفَرٍ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنَا شُعْبَةُ، عَنْ سَعْدٍ، عَنْ مُحَمَّدِ بْنِ عَمْرِو بْنِ الْحَسَنِ بْنِ عَلِيٍّ، قَالَ قَدِمَ الْحَجَّاجُ فَسَأَلْنَا جَابِرَ بْنَ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ فَقَالَ كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم يُصَلِّي الظُّهْرَ بِالْهَاجِرَةِ، وَالْعَصْرَ وَالشَّمْسُ نَقِيَّةٌ، وَالْمَغْرِبَ إِذَا وَجَبَتْ، وَالْعِشَاءَ أَحْيَانًا وَأَحْيَانًا، إِذَا رَآهُمُ اجْتَمَعُوا عَجَّلَ، وَإِذَا رَآهُمْ أَبْطَوْا أَخَّرَ، وَالصُّبْحَ كَانُوا ـ أَوْ كَانَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم يُصَلِّيهَا بِغَلَسٍ‏.‏

Isha prayer was offered by Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) [between the disappearance of twilight to the first third of the night](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/9).

> Narrated Ibn Shihab from Urwa:
>   Aisha said, "Once Allah's Messenger (PBUH) delayed the Isha' prayer till Umar reminded him by saying, "The prayer!" The women and children have slept. Then the Prophet (PBUH) came out and said, 'None amongst the dwellers of the earth has been waiting for it (the prayer) except you." Urwa said, "Nowhere except in Medina the prayer used to be offered (in those days)." He further said, "The Prophet (PBUH) used to offer the `Isha' prayer in the period between the disappearance of the twilight and the end of the first third of the night."
>
> حَدَّثَنَا أَيُّوبُ بْنُ سُلَيْمَانَ، قَالَ حَدَّثَنِي أَبُو بَكْرٍ، عَنْ سُلَيْمَانَ، قَالَ صَالِحُ بْنُ كَيْسَانَ أَخْبَرَنِي ابْنُ شِهَابٍ، عَنْ عُرْوَةَ، أَنَّ عَائِشَةَ، قَالَتْ أَعْتَمَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم بِالْعِشَاءِ حَتَّى نَادَاهُ عُمَرُ الصَّلاَةَ، نَامَ النِّسَاءُ وَالصِّبْيَانُ‏.‏ فَخَرَجَ فَقَالَ ‏ "‏ مَا يَنْتَظِرُهَا أَحَدٌ مِنْ أَهْلِ الأَرْضِ غَيْرُكُمْ ‏"‏‏.‏ قَالَ وَلاَ يُصَلَّى يَوْمَئِذٍ إِلاَّ بِالْمَدِينَةِ، وَكَانُوا يُصَلُّونَ فِيمَا بَيْنَ أَنْ يَغِيبَ الشَّفَقُ إِلَى ثُلُثِ اللَّيْلِ الأَوَّلِ‏.‏

So I postulate that if you do it after maghrib and after the disappearance of twilight then it is fine, although Muhammad (PBUH) himself preferred to do it rather late. And Allah knows the best.

Answer (score 0):

Salam,
one can offer prayer between its start and end times, any prayer before its time has started is null and void.
in your case, maybe you can go to sleep after Maghrib and offer Isha in the late night. make sure that to offer Isha before Fajr time is started.

wassalam,
Brother.

Comment: Could you please provide reference to support your claims? Regarding the start and end time of Isha, and that beyond that it is void.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam.SE, brother provide some references to your answer as @mezhang said, then only it will be a valuable contribution to this community

Answer (score 0):

if what you name "isha time" is not really isha time start, then it is possible in high latitudes of earth in some time in summer side of year. "isha" time is given in prayer tables for that places but it is not really isha time start as it means for normal places.